# Fixing Add Row function in QTableView in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

This is my code for fetching data from the database and creating a table view using PyQt5. Basically, I am importing it in another file and calling it via a button. The output is fetching my database and showing it in correct table format. It is updating properly. The delete function also working properly. But Add function not working, crashing the app.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtSql, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class crud():

    def initializeModel(self,model):
        self.model.setTable('student')
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.model.select()
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Roll No")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Father Name")
        self.model.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Email")
        self.model.setHeaderData(4, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Mobile")
        self.model.setHeaderData(5, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Department")
        self.model.setHeaderData(6, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Section")
        self.model.setHeaderData(7, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Password")

    def createView(self,model):
        self.view=QTableView()
        self.view.setToolTip("Change the fields")
        self.view.setModel(model)
        return self.view

    def addrow(self,model):
        print(model.rowcount())
        ret=(model.insertRows(model.rowcount(),1))
        print(ret)

    def findrow(self,i):
        delrow=i.row()
        print(delrow)

    def datastudent(self):
        self.db=QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('atdata.db')
        self.model=QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        delrow=-1
        self.initializeModel(self.model)

        self.View1=self.createView("Table Model",self.model)
        self.View1.clicked.connect(self.findrow)

        self.dlg=QDialog()
        self.layout=QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.View1)

        self.button=QPushButton("Add a row")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.addrow)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.btn1=QPushButton("Delete a Row")
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda :self.model.removeRow(self.View1.currentIndex().row()))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1)

        self.dlg.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.dlg.setWindowTitle("My Database")
        self.dlg.setGeometry(100, 100, 1100, 600)
        self.dlg.exec_()
```

This the code of for add function and I am facing issue in it. This function is defined to add a new row in Database for insertion of data.

```
 def addrow(self,model):
        print(model.rowcount())
        ret=(model.insertRows(model.rowcount(),1))
        print(ret)
```

Note:- This code was working correctly but before I defined it in the class because I want to import it. My original code is **[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I2vYYjtrRk4GNKFOWcwqeDJVyOAIZn1v)**, do check out for reference.
Please Help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: share your atdata.db

Comment: This is link to my database [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YK8D-BEVpQsnV1s6U_iY8MMxZBxX6SFL) @eyllanesc

Comment: You just say you have a problem, what's the problem?

Comment: How do you use an object of the crud class?

Comment: Windows crashes on calling addrow function.

Comment: @eyllanesc I import the file and calls datastudent on click of button

Comment: the code you sample does not do anything, shows the complete code

Comment: @eyllanesc actually it is a part of project and is called by main project login file. Should I share you the complete project?

Comment: No, do not share the whole project, it would improve your question if you provide a [mcve], if you do not know what it is read the link, even though I am trying to solve your problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks. Though i am new to both python and stack overflow building my first project. Thanks I will surely read it.

Comment: @eyllanesc Basically I am trying to reproduce my this code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I2vYYjtrRk4GNKFOWcwqeDJVyOAIZn1v/view?usp=drivesdk and trying to define it in a class so that i can call it and use on a button.

Comment: It is not right to do this, the logic is different, so it is failing, for example a classic problem is the scope of the variables.

Comment: @eyllanesc What is supposed to done to correct it?

Comment: I'm creating an answer, wait a moment, out of it read about OOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of modifying a set of functions and statements to a class is not trivial, one of the main problems is caused by obviating the scopes of the variables within the methods, and that can cause problems, for example the clicked of a button does not pass any parameter so the model parameter of addrow does not exist and it will throw you that error, and surely you think that the self.model is the same as model, but it is not.

So I've taken the liberty of converting that class into a custom QDialog:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql 


class CrudDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CrudDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('atdata.db')

        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.view.setToolTip("Change the fields")
        self.view.setWindowTitle("Table Model")

        btn_add = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add a row")
        btn_add.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

        btn_del = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete a row")
        btn_del.clicked.connect(self.remove_row)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.view)
        lay.addWidget(btn_add)
        lay.addWidget(btn_del)

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable('student')
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.model.select()
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Roll No")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Father Name")
        self.model.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Email")
        self.model.setHeaderData(4, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Mobile")
        self.model.setHeaderData(5, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Department")
        self.model.setHeaderData(6, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Section")
        self.model.setHeaderData(7, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Password")
        self.view.setModel(self.model)

        self.resize(1100, 600)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def add_row(self):
        self.model.insertRows(self.model.rowCount(), 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def remove_row(self):
        self.model.removeRow(self.view.currentIndex().row())
        self.model.select()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Show")
    c = CrudDialog()
    button.clicked.connect(c.exec_)
    button.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And you should no longer call datastudent but to exec_:

```
self.crud_dialog = CrudDialog()
some_button.clicked.connect(self.crud_dialog.exec_)
```